# Passing a Parameter to a Query used in a Report

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, ms-access-reports

I am trying to pass a parameter to a query used in a report for a calculation, not a `where` string. I am doing this programmatically.

The `where` clause works fine but the parameter value does not get passed and the query asks for it.

In the report itself under the properties section for

```
Recordsource QryrptTaxiInvoice 
Filter [TaxiInvID] = 859, [HSTFactor] = .8
```

I have my parameter declared in the query.

But every time I launch the report is still asks for the parameter value.

Below is some of my code.

```vb
strReport = "rptTaxiInvoice"
strWhere = "[TaxiInvID] = " & Me.cboTaxiInvoices
DoCmd.OpenReport strReport,acViewPreview,,strWhere, acWindowNormal, "[ParamHSTFactor]=" & HSTFactor
```

Here is the query used in the report:

```sql
PARAMETERS HSTFactor Double;
SELECT [faceamount]*HSTFactor AS facenetofGST
FROM tblTaxiCos 
WHERE tblTaxiCos.prov)="ON"
```

Answer (score 1):

OK I figured it out.

I pass the parameter like this

DoCmd.SetParameter "HSTFactor", HSTFactor